# Delete an accidental extra installation of Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: dual-boot

I recently installed Ubuntu 11.10 as a dual boot on my system, then when on Windows I accidentally deleted the partition having Ubuntu.

The result - left with grub rescue screen on start up.

I fixed that with another installation of Ubuntu but now have 2 installations of Ubuntu on my system, that's both the old one and the new one, how do I remove one of them keeping only the Win7 and one Ubuntu in my system?

Comment: simply delete the partitions of the ubuntu system you want to remove and then run "sudo update-grub" from the other one. However, be careful not to delete the partition on which grub itself is installed (/boot). Else you have to boot from the ubuntu cd and repair the broken boot partition entry.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont have separate partition for /boot, I would recommend that you boot into the new Ubuntu install i.e the one installed later and delete the partition for older one and run `sudo update-grub` afterwards. You can then reclaim that disk space by creating a new partition in it.

If you do otherwise i.e boot into the older install of Ubuntu and delete the partition for new Ubuntu installation, you may get into the situation where Grub in MBR is trying to access "boot" directory in the partition you just deleted and therefore system will not boot. In this case you will need to re-install Grub. If you really want to follow this path, you will first need to download Grub Rescue disk and after you have deleted the partition for newer Ubuntu installation and ran `update-grub`, boot your system from the rescue disk and re-install Grub from there. You can find many excellent tutorials for this using Google but if you dont have any thing important in the old installation of Ubuntu, I will suggest that you stick to first approach.

**UPDATE:**
To answer the updated question, I believe you just need to run "`sudo update-grub`" from Ubuntu and your problem will be solved.

Comment: i'm new to this so don't know where to post, but wanted to let you know that didn't work.
all it did was to get me back to square one i.e grub rescue.